# "matchMedia" support in Dart

Tags: media-queries, dart

How to use window.matchMedia in Dart?

I have found corresponding method:

```dart
MediaQueryList matchMedia(String query)
```

And "MediaQueryList" method:

```dart
void addListener(MediaQueryListListener listener)
```

But: `MediaQueryListListener` has no constructor and looks like some sort of a generated stub.

I have [JS example](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/):

```dart
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 500px)" );

// media query event handler
if (matchMedia) {
    var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 500px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
    WidthChange(mq);
}

// media query change
function WidthChange(mq) {

    if (mq.matches) {
        // window width is at least 500px
    }
    else {
        // window width is less than 500px
    }

}
```

And it has good support http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia

Comment: `addListener` and `removeListener` don't seem to be implemented. Doing `reflect(mq)` only shows `matches` and `media` as available methods. Furthermore there is this issue: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=3338

Comment: @ KayZ issue from May 31, 2012 O_O  Well looks like i have no choice but emulate it with onresize and streams. Or just make frankenstein with native calls.

Comment: It's might be not implemented because dart2js claims to support IE9 and 'matchMedia' works only with IE10+. So it is possible that this Working Draft won't be implemented even in Dart release. And will require some low performance shim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [pointed in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745361/matchmedia-support-in-dart#comment29344359_19745361) it doesn't seem to be implemented in Dart for now.

However you can use *dart:js* to do that like this :

```dart
import 'dart:js';

main() {
  if (context['matchMedia'] != null) {
    final mq = context.callMethod('matchMedia', ['(min-width: 500px)']);
    mq.callMethod('addListener', [widthChange]);
    widthChange(mq);
  }
}
widthChange(mq) {
  if (mq['matches']) {
    print('window width is at least 500px');
  } else {
    print('window width is less than 500px');
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer!
```mq.callMethod('removeListener', [widthChange]);``` seems not to work. How can I unregister a listener?

Comment: @zoechi that's a dartium bug. The problem is not present with dart2js.

Comment: (dart2js) When i call js stuff with return value. Like context['location'] or context.callMethod('matchMedia', ['(min-width: 500px)']) I get error 'ReferenceError: DartObject is not defined' For context.callMethod('matchMedia') i get 'TypeError: Not enough arguments ' Is it some Dart proxy error with the return value?

Comment: You have to add `<script src="packages/browser/interop.js"></script>` to your html file.