# How to use MediaQueryList from Dart

Tags: dart

I am trying to use matchMedia and the returned MediaQueryList object from Dart, but it does not have the 'addListener' & 'removeListener' methods, how do I do that without warning/error from the analyzer?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19745361

Comment: This is terrible solution and one of the reasons I still invest in closure... thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Why is it terrible, except that it needs dart-js-interop?

Comment: no real tooling for this kind of calls. compared to closure - there we have externs at least. anyways it works so it'll be fine.